# Calculate a sequence of Markov chain values

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, probability, markov-chains

I have a Spark question, so for the input for each entity `k` I have a sequence of probability `p_i` with a value associated `v_i`, for example the data can look like this

```
entity | Probability | value
A      | 0.8         | 10
A      | 0.6         | 15
A      | 0.3         | 20
B      | 0.8         | 10
```

Then, for entity `A`, I'm expecting the avg value to be `0.8*10 + (1-0.8)*0.6*15 + (1-0.8)*(1-0.6)*0.3*20 + (1-0.8)*(1-0.6)*(1-0.3)*MAX_VALUE_DEFINED`.

How could I achieve this in Spark using `DataFrame agg func`? I found it's challenging given the complexity to `groupBy` entity and compute the sequence of results.

Comment: What is MAX_VALUE_DEFINED? And bigger question - the logic is not clear. Probabilities should somehow add up to 1. I don't see it neither in the table, nor in your calculation. Can you please explain your logic?

Comment: `MAX_VALUE_DEFINED` is just the largest value available here. The problem I was trying to solve is calculate avg waiting time for people to get their food, in which case Probability here means the acceptance rate at each dispatch and the last component here means no one accepts the delivery request.

Comment: Is MAX_VALUE_DEFINED provided as a constant? Does it differ for every entity? *It would really help if you calculated your output manually and edited your question to add the expected result.* I mean, you have already provided the input table. Now we need to see the expected output table. Use the "Edit" button under your question.

Comment: Yes `MAX_VALUE_DEFINED` will be a CONST and consistent across entity, let me provide more context in my question.

Comment: has any of the answers helped to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use UDF to perform such custom calculations. The idea is using [`collect_list`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list) to group all probab and values of `A` into one place so you can loop through it. However, `collect_list` does not respect the order of your records, therefore might lead to the wrong calculation. One way to fix it is generating ID for each row using [`monotonically_increasing_id`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id)

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

@F.pandas_udf('double')
def markov_udf(values):
    def markov(lst):
        # you can implement your markov logic here
        s = 0
        for i, prob, val in lst:
            s += prob
        return s
    return values.apply(markov)
    
(df
    .withColumn('id', F.monotonically_increasing_id())
    .groupBy('entity')
    .agg(F.array_sort(F.collect_list(F.array('id', 'probability', 'value'))).alias('values'))
    .withColumn('markov', markov_udf('values'))
    .show(10, False)
)

+------+------------------------------------------------------+------+
|entity|values                                                |markov|
+------+------------------------------------------------------+------+
|B     |[[3.0, 0.8, 10.0]]                                    |0.8   |
|A     |[[0.0, 0.8, 10.0], [1.0, 0.6, 15.0], [2.0, 0.3, 20.0]]|1.7   |
+------+------------------------------------------------------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better solution, but I think this does what you needed.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('A', 0.8, 10),
     ('A', 0.6, 15),
     ('A', 0.3, 20),
     ('B', 0.8, 10)],
    ['entity', 'Probability', 'value']
)

w_desc = W.partitionBy('entity').orderBy(F.desc('value'))
w_asc = W.partitionBy('entity').orderBy('value')
df = df.withColumn('_ent_max_val', F.max('value').over(w_desc))
df = df.withColumn('_prob2', 1 - F.col('Probability'))
df = df.withColumn('_cum_prob2', F.product('_prob2').over(w_asc) / F.col('_prob2'))
df = (df.groupBy('entity')
        .agg(F.round((F.max('_ent_max_val') * F.product('_prob2')
                     + F.sum(F.col('_cum_prob2') * F.col('Probability') * F.col('value'))
             ),2).alias('mean_value'))
)
df.show()
# +------+----------+
# |entity|mean_value|
# +------+----------+
# |     A|      11.4|
# |     B|      10.0|
# +------+----------+
```